# "Comparing Rows in MySQL between two tables

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

"I have two tables, 'announcement' and 'temp_announcement.' The 'announcement' table contains 15 rows, while the 'temp_announcement' table contains 21 rows. I need to compare the rows between these two tables and identify the differences. Since the 'announcement' table has 15 rows and the 'temp_announcement' table has 21 rows, I want to print the additional 6 rows present in the 'temp_announcement' table."

"I attempted to use the EXCEPT operator for comparing the tables, but encountered an error. The query is not providing the expected result. Any insights or corrections on how to properly use EXCEPT or alternative approaches would be appreciated."

"How can I compare the two tables to find the differing rows?"
"What SQL query can I use to achieve this result?"
"Are there any efficient ways to identify mismatched rows between two tables in MySQL?"

Comment: *I attempted to use the EXCEPT operator for comparing the tables, but encountered an error.* What is MySQL version? MySQL 8.0.31 and later needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql compare two tables and display only the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230378/mysql-compare-two-tables-and-display-only-the-difference)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column,
       CASE SUM(tnum) WHEN 1 THEN 'In table1 only'
                      WHEN 2 THEN 'In table2 only'
                      ELSE 'Something went wrong'
                      END `In what table`
FROM (SELECT column, 1 AS tnum FROM table1
      UNION
      SELECT column, 2         FROM table2) combine
GROUP BY column
HAVING SUM(tnum) < 3;
```

If you need only one-side difference, then

```
SELECT column
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table2
                   WHERE table1.column = table2.column );
```